# Cannot read warning messages on meta.

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta

Although I have to admit to being colorblind, I noticed that it was next to impossible for me to read the following warning messages:

> [image: Tag warning]

I can only discern that text by:
**a**. Selecting it
**b**. Changing the angle at which I view my TFT monitor.

I think being colorblind shouldn't have to mean I have to resort to such things. Perhaps the contrast could be changed, or the warning messages shown in their own `<div>` with a different background?

(I got another warning while trying to post this question, but since I didn't see it at first, I didn't even know I had to wait for 20 minutes to post it.)

Comment: I'm not colorblind and I find that quite hard to read as well.

Comment: OUCH! I also have vision issues. That was actually _painful_. More contrast, anyone?

Comment: this is a bug! ouch my eyes. fix is on the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.